# Using TStringGrid in Multi-Device Application with SQLite using C++Builder 10.3.2

Tags: c++builder

I designed an SQLite database application to run on Android using FireDAC components (`TFDConnection`, `TFDQuery`), a Navigator, and a `TStringGrid`. It connects to the database table and displays the records.

When clicking on the Insert button (+) in the Navigator, a new record is created. Entering field data works fine on editing each cell.

However, I want to copy DATE and TIME strings to two of the fields using `StringGrid->Cell[Col][Row] = string` on the `AfterInsert` event. The strings show in the grid columns, but are not entered in the dataset, and the post fails with an error stating that field DATE (or TIME) must have a value.

Is there a method to programmatically enter the values to avoid this?

Comment: Please show your actual code that you are having trouble with

Comment: The problem was solved by writing the strings to the dataset using: FDQuery->FieldByName("column")->AsString = string;

Comment: @JPedro You should post that as an answer instead of a comment. [You can answer your own questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)